# Free SVN 1.7 Client for mac

Tags: svn

I've seen a number of threads talking about SVN clients for mac... However, I need one that's SVN 1.7 compliant. Any suggestions?

Comment: He's a non programmer ... don't ask....  looks like we're stuck with 1.6.

Comment: In case someone is still looking and stumbles upon this page: Cornerstone has SVN 1.7 support since version 2.7 (early 2012).  http://www.zennaware.com/cornerstone/index.php

Answer (score 0):

I use [svnx](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/15527/svnx). Says it goes up to Subversion 1.6.11. though. You can also use [SmartSVN](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/20339/smartsvn). I don't think there's much more for free. I recommend CornerStone if you are prepared to pay a few bucks, or just the command line if you want maximum flexibility and be sure to be able to take advantage of all the latest features.

Comment: Thanks CornerStone loosk to be 1.6 too ... is that right or do they have a 1.7 version ?

Comment: It seems difficult to find out, you could always email their customer service if you want to be sure.

Comment: There is also Versions if you are ready to pay. http://versionsapp.com/